# What can cause the onUpdated event from Chrome Tabs API to never pass a URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have the following listener attached to the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event:

```
//background.js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {

    if (changeInfo.url) {
        // Save tabId if tab's url is being changed (aka. user is navigating)
        navigatedTIDs.push(tabId); 
    }

    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete' && info.url === undefined) { 
        let idx = navigatedTIDs.indexOf(tabId);

        if (idx == -1) {
            // Tab id was not previously saved -> user reloaded
            cleanUpStorage(tabId); //tab was reloaded 
        } else { 
            // Tab id was previously saved -> user navigated, didn't reload
            navigatedTIDs.splice(idx, 1) 
        }
    }
});
```

The `url` field in `changeInfo` object is supposed to contain "[The tab's URL if it has changed.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated)"
It randomly stopped passing this field inside `changeInfo`. I was using it to distinguish between the user navigating away and reloading a page.

I tested all kinds of cases and it never passes the url, neither in the `changeInfo`, nor in the `tab` object. It just stopped doing that randomly during testing. I even restarted my PC. I'm desperate.

What can cause such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I didn't have the tabs permission declared in my `manifest.json`...